# Qt using "mingw32-make" in command line with .exe file generation error

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I have used `qmake -project` and `qmake` in command line so far with the configuration of .pro file, Makefile.Debug and Makefile.Release has been worked out. But error happens when I try to use `mingw32-make` in command line to generate .exe for my project.

Errors imply that in line:

```
64 ****missing separator ...Stop
```

But in this case, I've set all the environment variables well for both `mingw32-make.exe` and `qmake.exe`.

Someone says I should add a Tab instead of a space in makefile.release at where the error happens(the error place only has a "<<"), but other errors happen when I make the change. And I think since the Makefiles are all generated automatically by the `qmake` command, so maybe that's not the real problem...
Here's the Error info and part of the Makefile.Release file for reference
:

```
Setting up environment for Qt usage...
Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!

D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64>cd D:\qtProgramme\helloworld

D:\qtProgramme\helloworld>mingw32-make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/qtProgramme/helloworld'
Makefile.Release:64: *** missing separator.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/qtProgramme/helloworld'
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2

D:\qtProgramme\helloworld>
```

And here is the Makefile.Release:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: helloworld
# Generated by qmake (3.1) (Qt 5.9.2)
# Project:  helloworld.pro
# Template: app
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile.Release

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = cl
CXX           = cl
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG
CFLAGS        = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -O2 -MD -W3 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I. -I. -I..\..\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include -I..\..\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I..\..\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc 
LINKER        = link
LFLAGS        = /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'"
LIBS          = /LIBPATH:D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\lib D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\lib\qtmain.lib /LIBPATH:C:\utils\my_sql\my_sql\lib /LIBPATH:C:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib shell32.lib D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Gui.lib D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Core.lib 
QMAKE         = D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe
IDC           = idc
IDL           = midl /NOLOGO
ZIP           = zip -r -9
DEF_FILE      = 
RES_FILE      = 
COPY          = copy /y
SED           = $(QMAKE) -install sed
COPY_FILE     = copy /y
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
DEL_FILE      = del
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
INSTALL_FILE    = copy /y
INSTALL_PROGRAM = copy /y
INSTALL_DIR     = xcopy /s /q /y /i
QINSTALL        = D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe -install qinstall
QINSTALL_PROGRAM = D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe -install qinstall -exe

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = release

####### Files

SOURCES       = main.cpp 
OBJECTS       = release\main.obj

DIST          =   main.cpp
QMAKE_TARGET  = helloworld
DESTDIR        = release\ #avoid trailing-slash linebreak
TARGET         = helloworld.exe
DESTDIR_TARGET = release\helloworld.exe

####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cc .cxx

{.}.cpp{release\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.cc{release\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.cxx{release\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.c{release\}.obj::
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<
<<

####### Build rules

first: all
all: Makefile.Release  $(DESTDIR_TARGET)

$(DESTDIR_TARGET):  $(OBJECTS) 
    $(LINKER) $(LFLAGS) /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:$(DESTDIR_TARGET) @<<
release\main.obj
$(LIBS)
<<

qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile.Release helloworld.pro

qmake_all: FORCE
```

Comment: It looks to me like your makefile is a qmake makefile and you're trying to run it using GNU make.  If true, that cannot work.  You have to go find `qmake` and use that, not GNU make.

Comment: Many thanks. But this makefile was generated automatically by using qmake. Now I want to use mingw32-make to generate the .exe file. If it's not the mingw32-make, than which command I should try instead. I've tried make, but can't work out.

Comment: I can't help you with that.  Maybe someone else who knows qmake can help.  All I can say is that the section of makefile in the _Implicit rules_ area is not valid GNU make syntax.  Neither are the other recipes: the `@<< ... <<` syntax is not valid in GNU make.

Comment: Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a MSVC build of Qt. That can be deduced by the installation path (D:\qt5.10\5.9.2\msvc2017_64) and the output "Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!".

QMake from an MSVC build of Qt produces MSVC-compatible makefiles (by default at least).

Install the MinGW build of Qt, and you can use the MinGW toolchain for your project.

Comment: Thanks! But my complier is MSVC C++ that I've chosen before. And my debugger is VS 2017x64 which I set by myself. So in that case, can I still use mingw32-make to generate .exe file? Or do you mean I have to install MinGW to use mingw32-make? If I want to generate .exe through cmd, what will be a better choice?

Comment: If you want to use mingw32-make, you must use MinGW and a MinGW build of Qt. 

I presume that you want to use mingw32-make, because nmake doesn't build in parallel? Then you can use jom which is an nmake clone that adds the known -j option to enable parallel builds. It's available here: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/jom/jom.zip